# Is it possible to use Python's property classes for Datastore from the Go runtime?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I am using the Go runtime on GAE (Managed VMs) with Datastore. Just recently I found [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses) page that talks about Types and Property classes in connection with the Python runtime and Expando.

I would like to use queries against `ListProperties` from Go. Is that possible? Of course I know that [`google.golang.org/appengine/datastore`](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/appengine/datastore) does not expose this feature.

Answer (score 1):

The golang datastore API supports list properties as far as I know.  So you should be able to have a property that is a `ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)` in python and `[]string` in go and they should interoperate fine.